# How to set multiple UILocalNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilocalnotification

In my app I am using `UILocalNotifications`. I want to set notifications for different days of the week.For that, I have different dates in an array. But I am getting wrong results. Is there anything wrong with my code. My code is

```
for(int counter=0 ;counter<[daysArray count]; counter++)
        {
            int day = [[daysArray objectAtIndex:counter] intValue];
            NSDate *specificDate = [self getDateOfSpecificDay:day];

            UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
            localNotification.fireDate = specificDate;
            localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
            localNotification.soundName = sound;
            localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",specificDate];
            localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";
            localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
            NSLog(@"%@",localNotification);
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked that your specificDate variable is getting the different date each time?

Comment: yes I've checked it's different each time.

Comment: can you show us days array?

Comment: provide what you get in `NSLog(@"specificDate==%@", specificDate);`

Comment: 2014-09-28 11:15:28 +0000
        2014-09-29 11:16:01 +0000
        2014-09-30 11:16:13 +0000
        2014-10-01 11:16:25 +0000
        2014-09-25 11:16:38 +0000
        2014-09-26 11:16:57 +0000
        2014-09-27 11:17:07 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have done something similiar to your question but i dont know it will help you or not..just try this **NSWeekdayCalendarUnit**i suggest you just refer my answer.

NSCalendar *gregCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSArray *dobArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"02-08-2014", @"10-08-2014", @"14-08-2014", @"15-08-2014", @"16-08-2014", @"17-08-2014", @"18-08-2014", @"22-08-2014", @"28-08-2014", @"29-08-2014",nil];
NSArray *messagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Literacy And Numeracy workshop for parents and children", @"raksha Bandhan", @"Tri Colour Dat(School celebration)", @"Independence day (School Holiday)", @"PTM/Book Exhibition", @"Janmastami", @"Parsi New Year- School Holiday", @"Clown Day", @"Eco Friendly Ganesha-School Holiday", @"Ganesh Chaturthi-School Holiday",nil];
for (NSString *dobStr in dobArray)
{
    NSArray *components = [dobStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    if(components.count>2) {
        NSInteger aDay = [[components objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
        NSInteger aMonth = [[components objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
        // NSInteger aYear = [[components objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

        if(aDay == [dateComponent day] && aMonth == [dateComponent month]) { // dob is here
            [dateComponent setDay:aDay];
            [dateComponent setMonth:aMonth];
            [dateComponent setYear:[dateComponent year]];
            [dateComponent setHour:16];
            [dateComponent setMinute:54];

            UIDatePicker *dp = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
            [dp setDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents: dateComponent]];

            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            NSInteger index = [dobArray indexOfObject:dobStr];

            // [notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
            [notification setAlertBody:[messagesArray objectAtIndex:index]];

            [notification setFireDate:dp.date];
            [notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
            [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObject:notification]];
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think here you are misusing the line `localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;`

it will let your notification repeat every day of week that is creating problem in your case. Please remove this line and try again it will work.

Comment: I also want to repeat these notifications every day of the week as I've fired notifications for 7 dates.i.e 7 different days

Comment: But your each notification will repeat each day, like a notification fired on 2014-09-25 11:15:28 +0000 then on 2014-09-26 there will be two notification one of generated for 25th and another one is generated for 26th.

Comment: similarly on 30th september there will be 6 notification back to back.

Comment: So what I have to use if I want to repeat on every week at same time and same day?

Comment: Ok my mistake then can I know what kind of wrong results you are getting?

Comment: I am getting three alerts right after setting time from datepicker. Means if I choose 11:16:38 and now time is 11:14:32, alert appears immediatley